# Compare two array object, if a condition satisfied with one or more object then return whole array

Tags: javascript

I have two array objects arrayA and arrayB.

```
let arrayA = [
              {
                "category": "red",
                 "rank": 8,
                 "phone": 12345
            
              },{
                "category": "black",
                 "rank": 7,
                 "phone": 12332
                 }
             ]
let arrayB = [
              {
                "category": "red",
                 "rank": 4,
                 
            
              },{
                "category": "black",
                 "rank": 7,
                 
                 }
             ]

return array should be
arrayA = [
              {
                "category": "red",
                 "rank": 8,
                 "phone": 12345
            
              },{
                "category": "black",
                 "rank": 7,
                 "phone": 12332
                 }
             ]
```

So in the above arrays **category** is unique for each object. so while comparing **if any of the object's** **rank** in arrayA is *equal to or greater than* respective with the object in arrayB then return the whole arrayA else return nothing.

In the above arrays in category of *red*, rank of arrayA is greater(rank -> 8) than the rank of arrayB(rank -> 4) in the red category so arrayA need to return.
In case if the in arrayA rank in category "red" is less than the rank of respective in arrayB then return nothing.

I tried *some* method but filter one is filtering out the object from array which do not satisfied the condition, but I want whole array as it is if any of the some method's condition satisfied in one or more object.

```
let arrayC = arraA.filter(o1 => 
                arrayB.some(o2 => 
                  {return (o1.category=== o2.category&& o1.rank >= o2.rank)}));
```

can anybody help here?

Comment: Does the order remain the same for both arrays i.e `arrayA`, `arrayB`?

Comment: @HR01M8055 no, the order is not necessary.

Comment: Answered, Have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the order is not the same then you can [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to make it more efficient.

```js
let arrayA = [
  {
    category: "red",
    rank: 8,
    phone: 12345,
  },
  {
    category: "black",
    rank: 7,
    phone: 12332,
  },
];
let arrayB = [
  {
    category: "red",
    rank: 4,
  },
  {
    category: "black",
    rank: 7,
  },
];

const map = new Map(arrayB.map((o) => [o.category, o]));
const result = arrayA.some((o) => o.rank >= map.get(o.category).rank) ? arrayA: [];
console.log(result);
```

Comment: const map2 = new Map(arrayB.map((o) => [o.category, o]));
 const result = arrayA.filter( v => v.rank >= map2.get(v.category).rank)

This should reduce it quite a lot, I am not sure the intention of creating two maps and spcailly "result.push({ ...v })" v is already the desired object

Comment: @HR01M8055 so if i change the value of object {category: "red",rank: 8, phone: 12345,} of arrayA to {category: "red",rank: 3, phone: 12345,} the result should still have whole  arrayA, because the condition that need to satisfied is **greater then or equal to**.

so even if i changed the rank from 8 to 3 in category  "red" then  *equal to * condition should be satisfied with category "black" as rank is equal(that is 4) in both the array and return the whole array instead of filtering out.

Comment: @vandanamaurya *the result should still have whole arrayA*. No, that's not the case [CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/kumarmasterpraveen/pen/KKqNwwR?editors=0011)

Comment: @vandanamaurya Solution is working as expected.

Comment: I mean that the required result needed is: - if any of the cases is justified that is **greater than ** or **equal to**  for rank in **any of the objects**, The result should have the whole arrayA. 

so even in category **red** the rank of arrayA is 3 which is less than the rank of arrayB which is 4 the result array should have both objects as rank of arrayA in category **black** which  4 is equal to rank of arrayB.

Comment: If no object `rank` is greated than their respected `rank` thank what should be the result?

Comment: should result whole array as long as any of the rank is equal.

Comment: That's what I'm asking what if no rank is higher or equal then should It be an empty array?

Comment: if non of the rank is equal or greater than then result should be empty

Comment: hey @HR01M8055 it working now as I was expecting. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Looks pretty simple, I have added another case in the example, can you let us know if this is what you were looking for.
I compare the category of both the arrays and then compare rank.
if only 'b' has a higher rank object with same name category, I remove the object from result/

```js
let arrayA = [
              {
                "category": "red",
                 "rank": 8,
                 "phone": 12345
            
              },{
                "category": "black",
                 "rank": 7,
                 "phone": 12332
                 },
                 {
                "category": "orange",
                 "rank": 6,
                 "phone": 12332
                 }
             ]
let arrayB = [
              {
                "category": "red",
                 "rank": 4,
                 
            
              },{
                "category": "black",
                 "rank": 7,
                 },
{
                "category": "orange",
                 "rank": 12,
                 }
             ]
// dic had key: category and value as ArrayB objects
let dic = arrayB.reduce((dic,v) => (dic[v.category] = v, dic) , {})

let result  = arrayA.filter(a => dic[a.category].rank <= a.rank)
console.log(result)
```

Comment: You can make it more efficient with Map. Just in the case...

Comment: You should use Map because accessing value from Map is far more efficient than Object. [Read](https://medium.com/@bretcameron/how-javascript-maps-can-make-your-code-faster-90f56bf61d9d)

Comment: actually I have read the opposite where map is slower than dictionary.
Map has its benefit but i usually avoid for such simple things

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate the two arrays, and use a reducer.
Included logs so you can easily go through the code yourself.

```
const mergedArray = arrayA.concat(arrayB)

// We use a reducer to combine the merged Array.
mergedArray.reduce((acc, { category, rank, phone }) => {
  console.log(`category: ${category} - rank: ${rank} - phone: ${phone}`)
  
  // First find if the given category exist in accumulator
  const foundCategoryObject = acc.find(a => a.category === category)
  console.log(`foundCategoryObject: ${JSON.stringify(foundCategoryObject)}`)


  // If not found, simply add the found current object to acc and return
  if (!foundCategoryObject) return [...acc, { category: category, rank: rank, phone: phone }]
  // If not found, check if the later object has higher or lower rank
  else {
    if (foundCategoryObject.rank >= rank) {
      console.log(`"new" object has lower rank. Return original("old") object. (NO Change) ${category}-${rank}-${phone}`)
      return acc
    }
    else {
      console.log(`"new" object has higher rank. Return "nothing". Delete the "old" object and return acc. ${category}-${rank}-${phone}`)
     return acc.filter(a => a.category !== category)
    }
  }
}, [])
```